# want to apply the try catch for the batch file(alternative of try catch)

Tags: django, batch-file

i want to dump the data excluding contenttype. I am gerring error so that i wnt apply try catch to code.
So that i can find out what error i am facing.

```
set /p pathName=Enter The path where you want to take backup:%=%
@echo %pathName%
set d=%date:~-4,4%_%date:~-7,2%_%date:~0,2%
set d=%d: =_%
set t=%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%
set t=%t: =0%
md %pathName%\media
try{
    python dtz/manage.py dumpdata -e contenttype>> %pathName%/Backup_on_%d%_%t%.json
}
catch
{
    python dtz/manage.py dumpdata>> %pathName%/Backup_on_%d%_%t%.json
}
pause
xcopy dtz\templates\media %pathName%\media /s
```

Error i am getting `CommandError: Unknown app in excludes: contenttype`

Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no `try-catch` blocks in batch scripts. You need to use the `errorlevel` returned by a command to check whether it executed successfully or failed. **Generally** `errorlevel 0` indicates that the command executed successfully, but the errorlevel can also depend on the command/program being executed.

Details about [ERRORLEVEL](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/errorlevel.php).

ERRORLEVEL can be used as follows:

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (do something)
```